# Change in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, diff

I was using a bash script to do some automated testing on a CLI. All of a sudden it does not seem to work. Seems like our devops have done some changes to the OS.

The error i see is

```
bash-3.2$ sh cli-unit.sh 
cli-unit.sh: line 53: syntax error near unexpected token `('
cli-unit.sh: line 53: ` if ! diff < (echo "$EXPECTED") < (echo "$FOUND") > /dev/null; then'
```

The code part is

```
runTest() {
    local TITLE="$1"
    local BODY="$2"
    COUNTER=$((COUNTER + 1))

    local SHELL=$(getShell "$BODY")
    local EXPECTED=$(getOutput "$BODY")
    local FOUND=$(eval "$SHELL")

    if ! diff <(echo "$EXPECTED") <(echo "$FOUND") > /dev/null; then
        echo "--- FAIL: $TITLE"
        diff <(echo "$EXPECTED") <(echo "$FOUND")
        return 1
    fi
    PASSED=$((PASSED + 1))
    return 0
}
```

Can someone change/correct this for me ? i am unable to rectify it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whenever you have a shell syntax error, a good first step is to cut and paste your code into
[shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)
and correct the errors (important) and warnings (might be important) that it identifies. If you have trouble understanding its messages, then come here and ask

Comment: I have done the shellcheck and does not seem to have any error. But when i execute it, i still see the same error.

Comment: @sovenkat It will show errors if you add `#!/bin/sh` to the top of the shell code fragment in ShellCheck. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is clearly a `bash` script, but you are running it using `sh`.

Instead of explicitly using `sh` to start the script, either

1. Use `bash`, or
2. Make the script executable and add an appropriate `#!`-line on the first line that points to the `bash` interpreter, and run the script with `./cli-unit.sh`.

The `sh` shell can not be expected to understand `bash`-specific shell syntax.

---

I have a couple of further issues with some of the things in the bit of script that you show:

- Use lowercase shell variable names so that they don't accidentally clash with the system's environment variables.  In the code, you set `SHELL`, which usually is the path to the current shell interpreter.
- Don't use `diff` to do string comparison. Just do `if [ "$variable1" != "$variable2" ]` to test for inequality.
- Use `printf` rather than `echo` to output variable data (see "[Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)").

Addressing the `diff`:

```
if [ "$FOUND" != "$EXPECTED" ]; then
    # code as before
    return 1
fi
# code as before
return 0
```

Inside the `if` branch, you may still use `diff` to *show* the difference (especially if another script or user is *expecting* that sort of output from this script).  Another option would be to do

```
if [ "$FOUND" != "$EXPECTED" ]; then
    # $FOUND is different from $EXPECTED
    printf 'FAIL (%s): Found: %s\n' "$TITLE" "$FOUND"
    printf 'FAIL (%s): Expected: %s\n' "$TITLE" "$EXPECTED"
    # other code here
 fi
 # rest of script
```

or something similar.

Comment: does this look good ? `runTest() {
        local TITLE="$1"
        local BODY="$2"
        COUNTER=$((COUNTER + 1))

        local SHELL
        SHELL=$(getShell "$BODY")
        local EXPECTED
        EXPECTED=$(getOutput "$BODY")
        local FOUND
        FOUND=$(eval "$SHELL")
        local a="echo $EXPECTED"
        local b="echo $FOUND"

        if [ "$a" != "$b" ] > /dev/null
        then
                echo "--- FAIL: $TITLE"
        else [ "$a" = "$b" ]
                return 1
        fi
        PASSED=$((PASSED + 1))
        return 0
}
`

Comment: @sovenkat Just use `if [ "$EXPECTED" != "$FOUND" ]; then`. There is no need for extra variables to do the test and you don't need to redirect to `/dev/null`. _Inside_ the `if` branch, once you have determined that they are different, you may want to use `diff` to _show_ the difference. There is no need for the `else`.

Comment: @sovenkat See updated answer.